# How to write data to xml from database using aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have some stored proc.s that get data from DB.
I made some data access layers classes to get the data from the sql db
I have some Xml files that should be filled with this data. 
I'm supposed to link between them using aspx pages. 
Now, I want to know how can I read data at the aspx page from the xml file to send it to the server, and how can I write data from the db to the xml files.

I used to use json, but is there a method in which I can send and receive data without using json & just using XML ?

This is my XML File:

```
<allNews>
<news>
    <gNews>
        <flag>List of categories IDs this article linked to</flag>
        <title>news title goes here</title>
        <description>news description goes here</description>
        <date>news date goes here</date>
    </gNews>
</news>
```

This is the function that retrieves a list from the database:

```
XDataContext XDB = new XDataContext();

    public getCategoryContentListResult GetCategoryContentList(int contentID)
    {
        return XDB.getCategoryContentList(contentID).SingleOrDefault<getCategoryContentListResult>();
    }
```

I want to know how can I connect these two files using aspx.

When I used Json I used to do this: [I read data from an ajax call at the javascript file)

```
        private getCategoryContentListResult GetCategoryList()
        {     
              int ContentID = int.parse(Request.QueryString["country"]);     
              int res = getCategoryContentListResult(ContentID);
              JsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.Write(Request.QueryString["jsoncallback"] + "(" + JsonResponse + ");");
        Response.End();
```

Now I can't use Json, I just have to use XML. SO is there some method to do it ?

Comment: What have you tried? I don't really understand what you want to accomplish... "Write XML files", as in write to a file on the local file system? "Link between them using aspx pages", what does that mean, how do you define link in that sentence?

Comment: I don't know where to start from, so I didn't try anything. I just got lost while searching since it's my first time to use XML, so I thought to ask for some help "To know where to start searching from".

Comment: And what do you mean with "read data at the aspx page"? Do you want to read an xml file from the local filesystem? What does "read data and send it to the server" mean, can you provide an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Is what I want clear now, or Should I explain it again ?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect the two files"?

Comment: I mean , the xml file and the aspx file "the xml file and the server" ?

Comment: But that makes no sense, how do you connect the two? How do you *connect a file and a web server*?

Comment: Look, I'm sure there something missing, and we both don't get each other.

When you have the xml file "any xml file" is there some method to send the information stored in it to the aspx page?

Comment: Do you want to *download* the file to the *client* computer? As in the XML file should be outputted as is to the requesting client, similar to downloading a file?

Comment: You have a web server, with an XML file generated from a database as I understand it. This XML file, do you want a *client* (as in a computer requesting a page from the web server) to see this XML file as is? So you type http://example.com/request.aspx and see the XML code as the content in the page.

Comment: Well, the XML file is connected with the javascript page not the database, so it's switched... Data comes from HTML page stored in XML, sent to aspx page then stored to the database & viceversa.

Comment: I can't understand your question, sorry. It would help if you could provide an example of the output you expect, and where the output should go. Should it be saved to the server filesystem, as a response to the client requesting the page, or saved to the database? What do you mean with "XML file is connected with javascript page", specifically since Javascript is not a page..? What do you mean with "Data comes from HTML page stored in XML"? What data is that, how is the html page stored in XML?

Comment: Thank you soooo much @Patrick. I found this link: http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-create-xml.htm That's exactly what I wanted, I'm really sorry coz I wasn't able to clearly show what I want. Thanks a lot for your time & I'm sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the below code accordingly

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("your.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 2;
        writer.WriteStartElement("AllNews");
        writer.WriteStartElement("News");
        //Loopthrough your dataset/datatable/Or datareader here
        //Call the CreateNode Method from here 
        //End of loop
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();



    }

    private void createNode(string flag, string title, string desc, string date, XmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("GNEWS");
        writer.WriteStartElement("flag");
        writer.WriteString(flag);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("title");
        writer.WriteString(title);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("description");
        writer.WriteString(desc);
        writer.WriteStartElement("date");
        writer.WriteString(date);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

Hope this will help.